# Java class has an INVALID status after loadjava command in oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, loadjava

I have a problem with java class which I would like to load into oracle database.
There was no any output after using 'loadjava' in windows command line:

`loadjava -user lrn001/123456@LAND SharedAreaDecoder.class`

but I verified the status of my java class in sql developer and I found that it had an invalid status:
[user_objects table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfWMv.png)

The class has been compiled in Java 8. I am using oracle database 12c.
I've already tried to load another java classes and in each case the problem was the same so status was INVALID.
Besides that I tried to use resolve and here is the result:

`alter java class "SharedAreaDecoder" resolve;`

Script output:  Warning: execution completed with a warning. Java CLASS altered

The status after using the above command is still the same.

Using the below command gives more details:

```
loadjava -user lrn001/123456@LAND SharedAreaDecoder.class -resolve
```

errors : class SharedAreaDecoder ORA-29521: The name can't be found java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets The following operations failed class SharedAreaDecoder: resolution exiting : Failures occurred during processing

[My Oracle JVM version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsTWF.png)

[Select from user_erros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erjTl.png)

The error translation is: referenced name java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets could not be found

How to solve this issue?

Comment: A lot of information is missing here. Which version of Java? Which version of Oracle? What is the command line you used for loadjava? Did you use `resolve`? What research did you do, what did you try and what didn't work? Please [edit] your question and add this missing information.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I added some details. Could you take a look now?

Comment: And it was still invalid after the resolve? Note that you can also use `-resolve` on the `loadjava` command line. Did you check what the warning was?

Comment: After using loadjava with -resolve option I had the following output:                                errors   : class SharedAreaDecoder
    ORA-29521: The name can't be found java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets
The following operations failed
    class SharedAreaDecoder: resolution
exiting  : Failures occurred during processing

Comment: Sounds like your Oracle JVM is not actually 1.8. Now, please do some research: look for how to check the JVM version you have on Oracle, ensure you have it installed properly, ensure that you have all dependencies loaded. And if you still have a problem after that, remember to [edit] the question and put all that information **in the question itself**, not in the comments.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I added more details in the main post. But I'm still confused about the reason of my problem.

Comment: Does the `user_errors` view give you any more information about the issue?

Comment: @AlexPoole I added a screenshot from that table. There is only short description of an error which is not clear for me.